# Plugins for SASS (SCSS)

Tags: sublime-text

Can you recommend me working plugins for a better way to work with SASS and ST (autocomplete variables from all imported folders etc.)? Or maybe there is an another better editor than Sublime Text?

Now I'm using this plugins: SASS, SASS Build, Compass, SublimeOnSave. I love ST but working with SASS project is a little exhausting.